# Spring ConversionFailedException when adding JPA annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am learning Spring and I'm working my way through the tutorials. I have a form submission example and am trying to store the result using Hibernate/JPA. The example works with the following Entity:

```
package hello;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
//import javax.persistence.Entity;
//import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
//import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
//import javax.persistence.Id;

//@Entity
public class Comment {

//  @Id
//  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(min=2, max=150)
    private String comment;

    @Size(min=2, max=150)
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Comment[id=%d, comment='%s', name='%s']", id, comment, name);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

However if I remove the JPA commented lines the example throws the following exception when validating the form:

```
2016-11-04 14:59:32.716  WARN 17749 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request element: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [hello.Comment]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Comment'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Comment field..."
```

This seems to suggest it is trying to convert the value submitted for the "comment" field of the entity into a Long. Is it a case of providing an annotation to specify that the field is a String? I would have thought it would check the java type for this. Or am I doing something else wrong?
If you need the rest of the code let me know.

**Edit:** The error stopped when I removed this repository:

```
package hello;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface CommentRepository extends CrudRepository<Comment, Long> {

    List<Comment> findByName(String name);
}
```

Is there something wrong with the "Comment,Long" part? I copied these from the example and looking at the API for CrudRepository it looks correct as the Entity type is Comment and the ID type is Long.

I'm binding the values in a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in the following method:

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String checkPersonInfo(@Valid Comment comment, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "form";
    }

    return "redirect:/results";
}
```

Comment: Yes, the rest of the code is needed.  How are you binding your value to the entity?

Comment: Found the problem. It didn't like having a field with the same name as the entity. I changed the field "comment" to "commentText" and it worked. I assume somewhere it was trying to set the "comment" field to an instance of the Comment class.